# URL encode & decode

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlencode

Is there some plug-in or library to encode and decode URLs?

For example im doing that:

```
name='Jazmín Fernández'
self.redirect('/page?userName='+name)
```

But, obviously there are some characters that need to be encoded (í,  á, and the space between n and F). So, this give me an error.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarified that is Python.

Comment: Why the vote-down? did I something wrong?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Comment: Thanks, I used urllib. But still doesn't working. I did that:
    name='Jazmín Fernández'
    urlParams = urllib.urlencode({'userName': name})
and give me this error:
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xed' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert your unicode string to UTF8, before passing it to urllib.urlencode.

```
>>> name = u'Jazmín Fernández'
>>> urllib.urlencode({'name': name.encode('utf8')})
'name=Jazm%C3%ADn+Fern%C3%A1ndez'
```